# Execute command on all puppet nodes

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise, facter, puppetlabs-apache

I would like execute below simple command in all of my nodes which returns me whether symbolic links are available using puppet facter.

'ls -l | grep lrw | grep data'

How to run this command and collect the results from one client ?

I do not have puppet master and only have puppet node installed in all my client machines.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use pdsh to run remotely the command you want on any node you want, I don’t think you have to mes with any puppet stuff to accomplish you’re task

Check it out [this](https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2014/12/linux-cluster-sysadmin-parallel-command-execution-with-pdsh/) to get an idea how it works :)